# Django-model-utils Filter By Subclass

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-model-utils

I'm using [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html#inheritancemanager) inheritance manager to query a data model with multi-table inheritance and it mostly works great! What doesn't work great is when I want to `.select_subclasses()` but also filter for a specific subclass. For example:

```
class Salad:
    ...

class Vegetable:
    salad = models.ForeignKey(Salad)
    ...

class Cucumber(Vegetable):
    ...

class Carrot(Vegetable):
    ...
```

I would love to be able to just get ONLY all of the `Cucumber` objects related to a specific `Salad` without any `Carrot` objects. Unfortunately, the docs don't appear to explain this. Is my best option to create a `type` field on the `Vegetable` class that I set when saving any Vegetable object that would then be available for "regular" filtering? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to filter only `Cucumber` objects you could do something like this:

```
Vegetable.objects.exclude(cucumber__isnull=True)
```

Comment: This _maybe_ works, but isn't a very scalable solution when there are potentially MANY classes that extend Vegetable. Any classes that are created afterward that extend Vegetable will 'break' any existing queries that rely on filtering on `cucumber__isnull=True`. Can you think of another alternative?

Comment: Why should this break if you create new classes extending Vegetable?

Comment: Oh! I think I misunderstood. I'l give this a shot soon - thank you!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Marking as the correct answer. Relatedly, can you think of a way to not only filter for a specific subclass, but also filter on a field on that specific subclass in the same query? For example, if I only wanted `Cucumber` objects with a length greater than 12 centimeters.

Comment: Thanks! `Vegetable.objects.exclude(cucumber__isnull=True).filter(cucumber__length__gte=12)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.select_subclasses(Cucumber)` which would return the `Cucumber` objects and the rest as `Vegetable` objects. You could later filter it out using the `isinstance`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really answer the question. Because there may be MANY vegetable objects, it's far more efficient to filter at the query instead of afterward.